# Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm making a game where you are a soccer goalie and the ball(brazuca) keeps on falling down and you have to collect it, but I keep getting the incorrect number of arguments error. I'm fairly new to coding and I know that the error means something unexpected happened in the brackets where the error happened but I can't figure out how to fix it. It would be great if anyone can help me with this issue.

**class Gamescreen2**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;

    public class Gamescreen2 extends MovieClip
    {
        public var goalie:GoaliePlay;

        var gameMusic:GameMusic;
        var gameChannel:SoundChannel;
        var speed:Number;

        //public var army:Array;
        public var army2:Array;
        //public var gameTimer:Timer;
        public var gameTimer2:Timer;
        public static var tick:Number;
        public static var score:Number;

        public function Gamescreen2()
        {
            goalie = new GoaliePlay();
            addChild (goalie);

            gameMusic = new GameMusic;
            gameChannel = gameMusic.play(0,999);
            score = 0;

            //army = new Array();
            army2 = new Array();

            //gameTimer = new Timer(25);
            gameTimer2 = new Timer(25);
            //gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
            gameTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
            gameTimer2.start();

            tick = 0;
        }

        public function onTick(timerEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            tick ++;

            if (Math.random() < 0.05)
            {
                var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 550;
                var goalieB= new GoalieB(0,0);
                army2.push (goalieB);
                addChild (goalieB);
            }

            for each (var goalieB:GoalieB in army2)
            {
                goalieB.moveDownABit();

                if(goalieB.y == 420)
                {
                    score--
                    trace(score);
                    this.scoreTxttwo.text = score.toString();
                }

                if (goalie.collisionArea.hitTestObject(goalieB))
                {
                    goalieB.x == 550;
                    score += 10;
                }
                if (score < 1)
                {
                    score = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**class BrazucaPlay**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class BrazucaPlay extends MovieClip

    {
        var speed:Number;

        public function BrazucaPlay(startX:Number, startY:Number)
        {
            x = startX;
            y = startY;
            speed = Math.random();
        }

        public function moveDownABit():void
        {
            //two speed enemies
            if (speed >= .25)
            {
                y = y + 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post full error

Answer (score 1):

Might be the constructor of your `GameMusic` class.

```
gameMusic = new GameMusic;
```

You should have brackets like so:

```
gameMusic = new GameMusic();
```

Same with this line:

```
var newBrazuca = new BrazucaPlay;
```

Should be:

```
var newBrazuca = new BrazucaPlay();
```

If, after adding brackets `()` you still receive the error, then you should check your custom classes `BrazucaPlay` and `GoaliePlay` and make sure their constructors aren't expecting parameters.  Also check this function: `brazuca.moveDownABitB()`.

The constructor is the function that is named after the class and is what first runs when instantiate an object. So you do `var newBrazuca = new BrazucaPlay();` there is a constructor function in the `BrazucaPlay` class that would look something like this:

```
public function BrazucaPlay(){
    //some code.
}
```

If that function actually looked something like this:

```
public function BrazucaPlay(myParameter:String){ }
```

Then that would throw the error you're getting because it's expecting you to pass a parameter to it (in this case a string like `new BrazucaPlay("blah blah blah")`)

**EDIT**

Now that you've posted more code, the cause is quite clear.  The constructor of your `BrazucaPlay` class is expecting two arguments (a starting x/y position).  So when you instantiate a new `BrazucaPlay` instance, you are required to pass it those two parameters:

```
var newBrazuca = new BrazucaPlay(0,0);//you need to pass two numbers (starting x and y)
```

If you don't want to do this, you can change the code to make those parameter OPTIONAL.

```
 //this makes the parameters default to 0 if no value is passed in
 public function BrazucaPlay(startX:Number = 0, startY:Number = 0)
 {
    x = startX;
    y = startY;

    speed = Math.random();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that but I didn't understand when you said : make sure the functions (including the constructors) your calling from those classes (brazuca.moveDownABitB() etc.) don't have required parameters. Can you explain that?

Comment: Thank you, I will update my code as soon as possible and tell you what happend.

Comment: I tried what you told me to do but I still got the same error, I added the BrazucaPlay code in the code area, can you check what's wrong with it?

Comment: I did exactly what you said and now when I try to play the game works fine except for the fact that when it starts the ball falls down at the very left and just falls in a straight line and only spawns at (0,0) I want the ball to spawn at random points, how can I do that?

Comment: This outside the scope of your question, but it's pretty easy to do: `new BrazucaPlay(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth, Math.random() * stage.stageHeight);`

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is the most appropriate for finding your solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have one last question, when I play it the ball falls down and touches the goalie but the score goes up by like 200 instead of 10 I know it's because the ball keeps on touching the goalie until it moves away so is there a way to get it off the stage when it touches the goalie?

Comment: `if(goalieB && goalieB.parent) removeChild(goalieB)`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, user. Okay, a couple of things...

First, just so you know, we need the entire error, as CyanAngel said. It helps us prevent digging through the entire code. (For more tips about getting started, go to [stackoverflow.com/help](https://stackoverflow.com/help))

**Second, this is what your error message means: You are passing the wrong number of arguments (values) to a function. The function requires exactly two, and you're passing more or less than you should.**

This is why we need the error: it has the line number of the error, letting us/you narrow in on it directly.

Comment: I forgot to include where the error is, sorry about that, it is in this line  "var newBrazuca = new BrazucaPlay;" I believe this is what you were asking for. I tried moving the line around the code but nothing worked, I even checked the other classes which were perfectly fine, since I have 2 modes in the game and one mode works perfectly while this one doesn't work, and both have the same class functions.

Comment: LDMediaServices' answer should fix it, then.